# what is the int value of an enum in c?

Tags: java, c, eclipse, enums

I have this enum in c

Does enumeration go 0..n like in Java?

```
typedef enum tag_result
{
   // Success:
   succeeded   = 0,
   no_error    = 0,

   // General errors
   general_errors,
      err_failed,
      err_no_memory,
      err_invalid_argument,
      err_aborted
} result;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: Here's the [Oracle Tutorial for Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Trying it is insufficient. Many C programs appear to work, but actually rely on unspecified, undefined, or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @RohitJain: The question is about C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Actually when it comes to the number/index or - as java calls it - the ordinal `C` is more flexible, you can define a start or even define the number for each enum:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{ 
    printf("RED:   %d\n", (int) RED );
    printf("GREEN: %d\n", (int) GREEN );
    printf("BLUE:  %d\n", (int) BLUE );
    return 0;  
}
```

with

```
enum colors { RED, GREEN, BLUE};
```

the output will be

```
RED:   0
GREEN: 1
BLUE:  2
```

with

```
enum colors { RED = 4, GREEN, BLUE};
```

the output will be

```
RED:   4
GREEN: 5
BLUE:  6
```

with

```
enum colors { RED = 1, GREEN = 3, BLUE = 5};
```

the output will be

```
RED:   1
GREEN: 3
BLUE:  5
```

Comment: Using %d to print an enum is incorrect. You need to cast the value to  int.

Answer (score 1):

> Does enumeration go 0..n like in Java?

Yes it does

Answer (score 0):

yes, but this is something you can easily check by printing it value

```
 result r = general_errors;
 printf("%d\n", r );
 r = err_failed;
 printf("%d\n", r );
 r = err_no_memory;
 printf("%d\n", r );
 r = err_invalid_argument;
 printf("%d\n", r );
 r = err_aborted;
 printf("%d\n", r );
```

will print

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: Attempting to understand C through trial and error is dangerous. C has many areas which are undefined or implementation defined. For example, the code above incorrectly uses %d to print result. Result may not be compatible with int. In order to be correct, a cast is required.

Comment: @pburka woot? lol try it, it shows exactly what i said. and learn through trail and error is **ALWAYS** the best way, and this demonstrate it. give it a second and try it, you see it passes and show the integer value. in C# or java you need a cast. not in c

Comment: @NoIdeaForAName It works on YOUR compiler. But it's not portable C because it relies on implementation specific behavior. If sizeof(result) > sizeof(int) it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In C enums always start at 0 unless you explicitly specify another value. Any unspecified values will increase monotonically from the last specified value.

Note that the enum is only guaranteed to be an integer type large enough to represent the values in the enum. It might not be int. Some C compilers will use char or short for small enums.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default the value of the first enumerator is 0. But it is also possible to explicitly set the values of the enumerators in the specifier. Any subsequent enumerator must have the value value of the last enumerator plus one.

```
enum demo {
   first,
   second = 4,
   third,
   fourth
};
```

Here `first` will have a value of 0, but the remaining three will have values 4, 5, 6.

Answer (score 0):

C enums are ints.  The language just provides some syntax to do name to int replacement (and a few other items the compiler can enforce).

If you want a Java like enum, you need to create a bunch of global objects.  Since C lacks enforcement of the Java enum contracts, you will need to implement them as best one can.

So this complicates matters in two ways.  Now you need to simulate an object and simulate enums (if you want Java-like enums in c).

For simulating an object, there are a few techniques that work well.  The key is to quit early implementing only the features you need, because the more features you add, the harder is:

```
typedef struct tag_result {
   int enum_value;
   char* enum_name;
} result;

result* getEnumByValue(int index);

result* getEnumByName(char* name);
```

and in the `.c` file

```
// resize to match entries
int enum_limit = 5;
result enums[enum_limit];

// it is your responsibility to not duplicate values.
enums[0].enum_value = 0;
enums[0].enum_name = "invalid_argument";
enums[1].enum_value = 1;
enums[1].enum_name = "no_memory";

result* getEnumByName(char* name) {
  int index;
  for (index = 0; index < enum_limit; index++) {
     if (strcmp(enums[index].enum_name, name)) {
       return enums[index];
     }
  }
  return 0;
}

result* getEnumByValue(int value) {
        int index;
  for (index = 0; index < enum_limit; index++) {
     if (enums[index].enum_value == value) {
       return enums[index];
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want encapsulation, you could break out the struct into two parts, one exposed, one hidden.  The first technique is to only expose the `typedef struct s_result result`, letting the layout of the struct be defined in the `.h`.  It's a bit tricky at first, but it guarantees that nothing is exposed with an include and provides full access in the `.c` file.  If you go with this technique, you need to add accessor methods.

```
int getResultValue(result* item) {
   return (*item).enum_value;
}

char* getResultName(result* item) {
   return (*item).enum_name;
}
```

Some people break this out further, there is a "public" and a "private" header.  with one struct referring to the other (hidden by a void* pointer).  The idea is to hide the data by not exposing the type of the "private" header pointer.  Naturally to stitch the bits together, you need constructors that understand the wiring,

```
result* new_resultEnum(int value, char* name) {
  result* newItem = (result*)malloc(sizeof(struct s_result));
  (*newItem).private = (p_result*)malloc(sizeof(struct s_p_result));
  (*newItem).private.enum_value = value;
  (*newItem).private.enum_name = name;
  return newItem;
}
```

With such a technique, you can easily add member methods via C's function pointers (although the syntax is a bit challenging).

```
  ... added to the constructor above ...
  (*newItem).getValue = result_getValue;
```

exposing the "getValue" method publicly.  There is one caveat.  There's not really a good way to pass around the "this" pointer in C, because the member functions lack an ability to "know" they are in a structure, and to "know" where that structure starts.  Yes, there are workarounds, but they start to cost more time and money.  I typically just don't bother, which makes code like this quite common.

```
  result* myresult;
  (*myresult).getValue(myresult);
```

While I hope you liked the deeper scratch of the surface, odds are you should stop a lot sooner than member functions.  And probably I should have stopped a lot sooner than implementations of polymorphisim :)

Comment: And I didn't even get to polymorphic-like type handling.

Comment: C enums are not ints. According to 6.7.2.2#4 of the C99 specification, "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration."

Comment: Some of us have been using C before 99, but thanks for the update :)

Comment: C89 had similar wording and it was simply unspecified in K&R.

Comment: Yes, they are different in the sense that they are data types, but there are precious few implementations where the backing isn't something that resembles an int.  Much in the same way that a `struct A` and a `struct B` lead to `a*` and `b*` pointers, but the actual backing of both are addresses.  Splitting hairs?  Perhaps, but I wasn't saying anyone was wrong.